How to use `.is_zero_matrix` in sympy to check if it's a zero matrix?
Consider the following code
c=Symbol("c", real=True)
Matrix([[0, 0], [0, c/(192*pi**4) - 1/(192*pi**4) + 1/(64*pi**5),]]).is_zero_matrix

the result was
print(Matrix([[0, 0], [0, c/(192*pi**4) - 1/(192*pi**4) + 1/(64*pi**5),]]).is_zero_matrix)
None

Is this a built in feature(since it could possibly be zero by chose c specifically) or is it a bug? Is there a way to go around it? I used
Matrix([[0, 0], [0, c/(192*pi**4) - 1/(192*pi**4) + 1/(64*pi**5),]])==zeros(2)
False

but that's not very convenient for changing matrix size.

None means that it may or may not be zero depending on the value of the symbols. You can check if M.is_zero_matrix is True or any(M) etc.

If you want to know if a matrix could be zero if some symbol had the right value you could try solve(matrix, dict=True) -- if you get a solution then it could be zero, if you get [] then either there was no known solution or there is no solution. In your case, doing so gives [{c: (-3 + pi)/pi}] so you know it could be zero.
